# How to import cv2 in python 3.5 64bit?

Tags: permissions, python, opencv

My machine is windows machine. I have Ubuntu hosted in virtual box. I used `apt-get` to install `opencv-python`. Now when I try to import cv2, I get an error message: `Import Error: No module named cv2`. I have python 2.7 and 3.5, but I have changed the interpreter from python 2.7 to 3.5 in my Pycharm IDE. I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

When I try to use `pip` to install `opencv`, I get an error message: `Permission denied`. How do I install `opencv` using python 3.5 64bit without running into these nasty errors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37188623/ubuntu-how-to-install-opencv-for-python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed conda [based on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40207011/opencv-not-working-properly-with-python-on-linux-with-anaconda-getting-error-th) and in Pycharm, I changed the interpreter to the anaconda python; and that did the trick.

```
conda remove opencv
conda update conda
conda install --channel menpo opencv
```

But destroyAllWindows() function is still giving me errors. I will find out what's going on.